# OOP design problem. Two kinds of empty Optional

Tags: java, object-oriented, coding-style

I'm writing a quite simple application that deals with hotel rooms reservation. I've got a problem at one stage.

I'm processing a queue of orders. For every order one of the receptionists should choose a room (one or none at all) for the client according to his strategy. That's why I decided to go with Java `Optional`. The problem is that if there are simply no free rooms at the desired date the order should be cancelled, but if there are some rooms available and none of them fit to the receptionist's strategy that order should be put back to the queue.

Choosing rooms definitely should be receptionist's duty. What do you think is the best way to deal with that problem in a clean way? Should I throw an exception instead of returning empty `Optional` when there are no rooms at date? Unfortunately, exceptions aren't usually a good solution for controlling the code flow.

Code fragment:

```
    Optional<Room> selectedRoom = receptionist.chooseRoom(rooms, 
                                                          order.getQuestionnaire());

    boolean decision = selectedRoom
            .map(room -> receptionist.askClient(order.getClient(), 
                                                room,
                                                order.getQuestionnaire()))
            .orElse(false);

    if (shouldProcessAgain(order, selectedRoom.isPresent(), decision)) {
        orders.add(order);
    }
```

Comment: What good does putting the order back in the queue do? Won't the reception just fail over and over again?

Comment: @WinstonEwert No. There are many receptionists that deal with orders and they've got different choosing strategies.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I would assume it does until the state of the hotel changes.

Comment: @PawełKoniarski please define 'strategy' in this context

Comment: This is a funny hotel you are running :P

Comment: So one receptionist might be a perfectionist and only chooses rooms that are a perfect fit for the client. Another one might be evil and choose the worst fit. There might be also one that chooses the most expensive from available rooms.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I can see why you think it's funny.  But after some of the hotel's I've been in it almost sounds typical. :)

Comment: @PawełKoniarski so if an order is put back in the queue it might be picked up by a different receptionist using a different strategy?

Comment: Yep, exactly like that. Receptionists are looped in a cycle and every next order is served by other receptionist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could model it in two ways:

**Option 1:** Using an wrapper + enum for the receptionist response:

```
enum ReceptionistDecision {
    BOOK_ROOM,
    NO_ROOM,
    RETURN_TO_QUEUE,
}

class ReceptionistResponse {
    ReceptionistDecision Decision;
    Optional<Room> Room;

    ReceptionistResponse(Room room) {
        ...
    }

    ReceptionistResponse(ReceptionistDecision decision) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** Or you could an interface class, and make each of the responses inherit from it. Something like:

```
interface class ReceptionistResponse {

}

class ReturnToQueueReceptionistResponse implements ReceptionistResponse {

}

class NoRoomsBookedQueueReceptionistResponse implements ReceptionistResponse {

}

class RoomBookedReceptionistResponse implements ReceptionistResponse {
    Room BookedRoom;
}
```

The `chooseRoom` method would be:

```
ReceptionistResponse chooseRoom(List<Rooms> allRooms, Questionnaire questionnaire) {
    if (/* all rooms are full */) {
        // Option 1
        return new ReceptionistResponse(ReceptionistDecision.RETURN_TO_QUEUE);

        // Option 2
        return new ReturnToQueueReceptionistResponse();
    }

    if (/* Choose no rooms */) {
        // Option 1
        return new ReceptionistResponse(ReceptionistDecision.NO_ROOM);

        // Option 2
        return new NoRoomsBookedQueueReceptionistResponse();
    }

    if (/* Choose some room */) {
        // Option 1
        return new ReceptionistResponse(choosenRoom);

        // Option 2
        return new RoomBookedReceptionistResponse(choosenRoom);
    }
}
```

And the client code for option 1:

ReceptionistResponse response = receptionist.chooseRoom(rooms, order.getQuestionnaire());

```
// options 1
if (response.Decision == ReceptionistDecision.RETURN_TO_QUEUE) {
// option 2
if (response instanceof(ReturnToQueueReceptionistResponse)) {

    orders.add(order);
}
```

Comment: I have decided to go with something close to your first option. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of approaches one could apply to modelling this.

First, we might have the passive receptionist. The passive receptionist decides what to do, but doesn't do anything. Instead, we have class something like

```
public class ReceptionistResponse {
    public static ReceptionistResponse bookRoom(Room room);
    public static ReceptionistResponse cancelOrder();
    public static ReceptionistResponse returnToQueue();
}
```

Now, you  may notice that this is the same basic idea as optional, but we've extended it to three options instead of just one. Each static method creates and returns a particular response. Then your receptionist has a method

```
ReceptionistReponse attemptBookOrder(Order order) {
    ...
    return ReceptionistResponse.bookRoom(room);
    ...
}
```

The calling code takes the ReceptionistResponse and undertakes the necessary response.

Alternatively, you might have an active receptionist. The active receptionist actually does the actions:

```
void attemptBookOrder(Order order) {
    if (rooms.allRoomsAreFull()) {
       order.cancel();
    }
    if (...) {
       order.bookRoom(room);
    } else {
       orderQueue.put(order);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you structure the ReceptionistResponse to handle the three possible responses? An enum plus an optional Room field? What about a case where the different responses each had numerous properties (e.g. percentMatched or roomsAvailable)?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius, you could either use the enum with optional, or multiple subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Returning the Optional seems OK but if there is no value the logic should not proceed. Each guest has a real room assigned to it or it is not a guest. So once the receptionist decided to return an empty Optional, the order should be put back in the queue and nothing more.

It is fine to first take the order from the queue, then perform the receptionist.chooseRoom and if it comes back empty, re-add the order to (the end of) the queue. I would wrap that in a try-finally to make sure no orders get lost.

If a room does get selected, it should proceed as a room, not an Optional. Optional should be used as a temporary variable only because its only purpose is to detect that the receptionist decided to not handle the order for the moment.